# Why is my menu not overlapping my elements that use JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get my dropdown navigation to be on top of everything. I can only get it to go on top of HTML elements using no JQuery. So everything with JQuery overlaps it when I hover over it. What am I missing?

```
#container{
float:right;
width: 72%;
margin-right:2%;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
display:block;
z-index:999;
}

.menu ul ul {
display:none;
position:absolute;
left:92%;
margin-top:-3.3em;
}
```

Using JQuery in my content: http://michellecantin.ca/test/features/accordions/ http://michellecantin.ca/test/features/grids/

Using no JQuery in my content: http://michellecantin.ca/test/

Why is my menu not overlapping my elements that use JQuery? What do I do to fix it?

Comment: You should look into stacking and z-index

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: @ravb79 http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @jbaby Noted. You could've also posted another reference point, though.

Comment: Whatever DOM element in your html that is placed in a descending order will stack on top of its previous sibling/parent(if they both have positioning on them which yours do) like a natural `z-index`. Here is another good article, http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/.

Comment: elements created with jquery are no different than elements that you create with html. you really should include the relevant html in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your problem:

Change this style:

```
.accordion-style1 dt a span, .accordion-style2 dt a span, .accordion-style3 dt a span, .accordion-style4 dt a span {
    font: 2em PulsarJS;
    margin-top: -0.15em;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0.2em;
    transition: color 0.5s ease 0s, text-shadow 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

To this:

```
.accordion-style1 dt a span, .accordion-style2 dt a span, .accordion-style3 dt a span, .accordion-style4 dt a span {
    font: 2em PulsarJS;
    margin-top: -0.15em;
    float:right;
    transition: color 0.5s ease 0s, text-shadow 0.5s ease 0s;
}
```

And change this style:

```
.accordion-style1 dt a:link, .accordion-style1 dt a:active, .accordion-style1 dt a:visited, .accordion-style2 dt a:link, .accordion-style2 dt a:active, .accordion-style2 dt a:visited, .accordion-style3 dt a:link, .accordion-style3 dt a:active, .accordion-style3 dt a:visited, .accordion-style4 dt a:link, .accordion-style4 dt a:active, .accordion-style4 dt a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.75em;
    position: relative;
}
```

To this;

```
.accordion-style1 dt a:link, .accordion-style1 dt a:active, .accordion-style1 dt a:visited, .accordion-style2 dt a:link, .accordion-style2 dt a:active, .accordion-style2 dt a:visited, .accordion-style3 dt a:link, .accordion-style3 dt a:active, .accordion-style3 dt a:visited, .accordion-style4 dt a:link, .accordion-style4 dt a:active, .accordion-style4 dt a:visited {
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 0.75em;
}
```